# Как в Intellij IDEA создать новую ветку для Git?

Tags: git, java, intellij-idea, github

Всем привет!

Есть почти готовый проект, он лежит в master-ветке на github.com.

Создаю новую ветку new_branch в `Intellij IDEA: VCS -> Git -> Branches -> '+ New branch'`

Ну вроде создалась ветка, переключаюсь на неё.

НО, когда что-либо добавляю/изменяю в файлах, при попытке запушить изменения, в одном из окошек пишет

> new_branch no tracked branch. Use the checkbox below to push branch to manually specified...

и в итоге ничего не пушит мне на сервер. Всплывает "push rejected"

Что не так делаю?

Объясните, пожалуйста, поподробнее, если можно.

Благодарю.

Comment: Вы создали локальную ветку, на сервере нет соответствия ей. Вот git и просит привязаться к удаленной ветке и подсказывает Вам, что нужно нажать checkbox (где он - не знаю, я идеей пользовался, но git команды делал только в консольке). Но похоже [здесь](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/pushing-changes-to-the-upstream-(git-push).html) описан Ваш случай. Если коротко, то нужно вначале закоммитить свои изменения, потом сделать pull и только потом push.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

На самом деле, всё довольно просто. Вам следует отметить чекбокс в этом окне и выбрать соответствующую удалённую ветку, в общем-то, что и сообщает вам IDE. Это достаточно сделать лишь в первый раз, поскольку в дальнейшем git уже будет знать эти связи (tracking branches).